# A char copying function

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to use a function I wrote called strLength to count a number of characters passed, then will mallocate the number in addition to a NULL terminator, then copy the characters and return the copy.

so far I have:

```
int strLength(char* toCount)
{
    int count = 0;

    while(*toCount != '\0')
    {
        count++;
        toCount++;
    }

    return count;
}

char* strCopy(char *s)
{
    int length = strLength(s);

    char *copy = malloc(length+1);

    while(s != '\0')
    {

        s++;
    }

    return copy;
}
```

strCopy is the function I need help with. I also can not use strcpy or memcpy, I'm just writing this on my own to create my own string library. I think before the `s++` I should have something along the lines of `copy += s` but I am not sure that would work.

I am a bit of a newbie, so please bear with me

Comment: How do you typically assign values to a variable?  And how do you access elements of an array such as copy?

Comment: Have you looked at the function `strdup`? It does pretty much exactly what you are trying to make.

Comment: Can I treat it as an array and just use s[i] and write a for loop instead?

Comment: Given that you have the count of characters, why not?

Comment: Worth reading: [Back to Basics - Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Answer (score 1):

Copy from the end to the beginning looks like a quick approach.
Check for a NULL allocation.

```
char* strCopy(char *s) {
  int length = strLength(s) + 1;
  char *copy = malloc(length);
  if (copy != NULL) {
    while (length > 0) {
      length--;
      copy[length] = s[length];
    }
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working for me. I hope this helps.

```
char* strCopy(char *s)
    {
        char *copy = (char*) malloc(strLength(s) + 1);
        int index = 0;
        while(s[index] != '\0')
        {
            copy[index] = s[index];
            index++;
        }
        return copy;
    }
```